# Couldn't connect to my Oracle database with Tableau Desktop

Tags: oracle, database-connection, tableau-api

I'm trying to use my oracle data in Tableau but I couldn't connect to my database. I'm using Oracle SID. Here the message error i get:

> Erreur au niveau de la base de données Oracle (12541) : ORA-12541: TNS
> : pas de processus d'écoute  Impossible de se connecter au serveur
> Oracle "desktop-49t8ps8". Vérifiez que le serveur est en cours
> d'exécution et que vous disposez des droits nécessaires pour accéder à
> la base de données demandée.

Which translates as:

> Oracle database error (12541): ORA-12541: TNS: no listener Unable to connect to Oracle server "desktop-49t8ps8". Check that the server is running and that you have the necessary rights to access the requested database.

[image]
edit :
[image]

Comment: The message says there is no listener; so check what address `desktop-49t8ps8` resolves to, and see if there is anything listening on port 1521. If that is your local machine, perhaps the listener is only on localhost, and you can connect through that instead? (You should be using the service name rather than the SID, but it isn't getting far enough for that to matter...)

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried localhost, it worked but i couldn't find my tables

Comment: Then are you connected to the right instance and user? `c##hba` is a common user (not sure you really want one of those though?) so I suspect you're connecting to the CDB instead of the PDB; again, you should be using the service name, not the SID - if the SID works then it's probably the same as the CDB  service, and you need the PDB service instead.

Comment: @AlexPoole i edited the question to addone more screenshot about oracle information. the user name i used is c##hiba

Comment: Don't connect as the c## user, also confirm you're connecting to the PDB service name... basically what Alex said

Comment: OK, I slightly misread the value from your screenshot. It's still a common user [see the docs for the difference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/overview-of-the-multitenant-architecture.html#GUID-3BB161DA-9CC0-4D61-A2C1-5D3662E0DECF). Based on your SQL\*Plus session and updated connection info you should see the same data (tables) in both now. `orcl` is probably the CDB though, right? So where have you created tables owned by that user?

Comment: I used oracle sql developper and i imported my files.i tried select * customer (one of my tables) in sqlPlus and it's working. Maybe localhost is wrong. I'm really confused , i'm new to oracle . Thank you for answering

Comment: OK, so SQL\*Plus is showing thr host, not the service. What does `sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME')` show in both sessions?

Comment: it shows sys$users